# Silverlight and RIA Services - Using the ActivityControl with Custom DataContext

Tags: silverlight, service, ria

I am using Silverlight 3 and .NET RIA Services.  I would like to use the ActivityControl from David Poll: http://www.davidpoll.com/?p=4.

Is this possible outside of a DomainDataSource (I am not using the DDS)?  I would like to programmatically bind to it, i.e. similar to how I bind my other controls via code-behind, via the DataContext.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it outside of a DDS. You just need some kind of IsBusy property to bind to which you set to true when you're working and false when you're done. One thing I've done is to wrap the DomainContext in another class and then expose an IsBusy property from that.

If you'd like to see some code for this let me know and I'll update this response with it.